# AIR3.5 AS3 application doesn't launch when device is in the landscape mode with aspectRatio set to "ANY"

Tags: actionscript-3, air, screen-orientation, aspect-ratio, device-orientation

I set aspect ratio to ANY:

```
stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.ANY);
```

If I launch my application when device is rotated to landscape, I see only black screen. But when device is rotated to portrait, application launches normally and then I rotate device to landscape or portrait and application re-orients user interface respectively. I have some kind of solution of this problem. If I add this line of code:

```
stage.setOrientation(StageOrientation.DEFAULT);
```

application launches in portrait when device is in landscape, and it remains in portrait until I rotate device to portrait and back to landscape. I want my application to start with UI oriented respectively to device orientation.

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit the appdescriptor xml as well..

```
    <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
```

Comment: you can also set the default orientation here as well.

Comment: No, this is not the reason of that problem. My appdescriptor is correct. Here is my settings:
<initialWindow>
    <content>MyApp.swf</content>
    <aspectRatio>any</aspectRatio>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
    <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
 </initialWindow>

Comment: When application is running resize event is thrown, but how can it be thrown at the very start when i'm holding device still?

Comment: well, I'm a flash developer, so as I know, its browser-dependant. In your case its not. I tought its worth a shot to try. Something else is wrong then, but the code you1ve included doesn1t make any clue.